# Block Caret keeps activating when I highlight words in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, syntax-highlighting, caret

I just downloaded the newest version of Android Studio as I just switched my computers.  I realized pretty quickly that there is a weird issue where when double-clicking anything, whether it's a word, variable, comment, etc. it highlights the word, but attaches a block caret on the last letter which then is activated for all other clicking I do within the application. I've tried restarting Android Studio, activating the block caret setting and deactivating again.  I've checked the shortcuts settings to make sure there is no shortcut set up for activating the block caret.  The only thing that's been able to fix it is by pressing the "fn" + "a" keys on my computer (MacBook pro).  I don't want to have to click "fn" + "a" every other minute while developing.  Does anyone know how I can fix it from activating the block caret each time I try and highlight?

This is what happens when I try highlighting.  The black box around the "e" is what is bothering me.

[image: This is what happens when I try highlighting. The black box around the e is what is bothering me.]

[image: This is what I'd like to happen, after clicking outside of the highlighted word it should just place a cursor behind whatever letter I'm on, not highlight it with a block.]

This is what I'd like to happen, after clicking outside of the highlighted word it should just place a cursor behind whatever letter I'm on, not highlight it with a block.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that it seems Android Studio defaults to having the "Idea Vim" plugin activated when you initially install it.  By going to tools > Idea Vim and just unchecking it my text editing issues were resolved.